# Android Java - Issues setting ImageView visibility when calling from non main class

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am relatively new to Android development and I'm writing a simple two player TicTacToe game that sends turns back and forward across a socket connection.

I've set the X and O graphics on all the squares and am controlling the visibility via a class that holds both the array holding the square status and the method for updating the graphics.

I also have a listener class running in the background which receives data to update the array from the remote player.

When I call the UpdateGraphics method from the main thread it all works fine, the board updates as expected based on the array and the graphics show as expected. When I call the same method from the listener thread the app crashes ONLY when making one of the ImageViews visible, but it handles making them invisible OK. I can't see what's causing the crash, it's specific to calling setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE) from the listener thread, everything else works as it should.

The ImageViews are passed as an array from the main thread. I've tried both passing the ImageViews directly into the UpdateGraphics method and passing them into the TrackGrid class, it doesn't make a difference.

I've tried using setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE) and setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), the result was the same.

Class which tracks the grid status:

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Context;

public class TrackGrid {
    int[] tileStatus = new int[9];
    Context context;
    ImageView[] boardGraphics;

    TrackGrid (Context cont, ImageView[] boardGraphics){
        context = cont;
        this.boardGraphics = boardGraphics;
    }
    public boolean UpdateGrid (int player, int reference){
        boolean validMove;
        if (tileStatus[reference]==0) {
            tileStatus[reference] = player;
            validMove = true;
        } else {
            validMove = false;
        }
        return validMove;
    }

    public void ResetGrid (){
        for (int f=0; f<9; f++){
            tileStatus[f]=0;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateGraphics (){
         for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            if (this.tileStatus[x] == -1) {
                boardGraphics[x].setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            } else if (this.tileStatus[x] == 1) {
                boardGraphics[x + 9].setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                boardGraphics[x].setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                boardGraphics[x + 9].setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Listener class:

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainListener implements Runnable{
    Context context;
    Thread t;
    String tName;
    TrackGrid tgOb;
    TextView textBox;
    SocketConn sConn;
    DataInputStream in;

    MainListener (SocketConn sConn, Context context, String tName, TrackGrid gridManager, TextView textBox, ImageView[] gridView){
        this.context = context;
        this.tName = tName;
        t = new Thread(this, this.tName);
        this.tgOb = gridManager;
        this.textBox = textBox;
        this.sConn = sConn;
    }

    public void run() {
        //Check socket connection and wait
        while (sConn.socket.isConnected() == false) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(sConn.socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            String line = "";
            int retry = 1;
            do {
                try {
                    String[] tempArrayStr = new String[9];
                    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
                        line = in.readUTF();
                        tempArrayStr[r] = line;
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
                        tgOb.tileStatus[x] = Integer.parseInt(tempArrayStr[x]);
                    }
                    tgOb.UpdateGraphics();

                } catch (IOException i) {
                    //System.out.println("Communication lost");
                }

            } while (true);

        }
    }
    public void CloseStream(){
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call ```runOnUiThread()``` while you are working on UI in new thread?

Comment: @Enowneb, that worked, thanks! Didn't realise UI updates had to be made in the main thread.